# Trying to use the deformation theorem to solve integral

Tags: complex-analysis, problem-solving

I have this integral:

> $$\int_{|z|=2}\frac{\cosh z}{(z+1)^3(z-1)}dz$$

Both singularities $z=1,z=-1$ are *inside* the circle. I have already solve this using partial fractions, and I don't have much problem with that (I got $-\frac{\pi i}e$). Now I want to solve it with the deformation theorem, but I'm having trouble with it. I say the hypothesis are satisfied, if we consider $\Gamma$ as the circle $|z|=2$, and $f(z)=\frac{\cosh z}{(z+1)^3(z-1)}$ where $f$ is analytic in $\Bbb C\setminus \{-1,1\}$, so how do I find $C^1$ curves that work? I have considered the curves $|z-1|=1/4$ and $|z+1|=1/4$ to *isolate* the singularities, but what next?

Comment: Consider the functions $f(z) = \frac{\cosh z}{z-1}$ and $g(z) = \frac{\cosh z}{(z+1)^3}$.

Comment: @DanielFischer Ok, we have that $f(z)$ is analytic in $\Bbb C\setminus\{1\}$ and $g(z)$ in $\Bbb C\setminus\{-1\}$ then (?): $$\int_{|z|=2}\frac{\cosh z}{(z+1)^3(z-1)}dz=\int_{|z+1|=\frac14}\frac{f(z)}{(z+1)^3}dz+\int_{|z-1|=\frac14 }\frac{g(z)}{z-1}dz \\ =\frac{2\pi i}{2!}f''(-1)+2\pi i \;g(1)$$ 
Is this what it is?

Comment: Yes, that's what I had in mind.

Comment: @DanielFischer Thank you so much... I'm so happy ` :) `